# Replacing specific words in a string (Python)

Tags: python, string, replace

I would like to replace words in a string sentence such as:

```
What $noun$ is $verb$?
```

What's the regular expression to replace the characters in '$ $'  (inclusive) with actual nouns/verbs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for that. I would do

```
string = "What $noun$ is $verb$?"
print string.replace("$noun$", "the heck")
```

Only use regular expressions when needed. It's generally slower.

Comment: Could string the replaces together as well: `str.replace("$noun$", noun).replace("$verb$", verb)`

Comment: I have a database of a list of words and the type (Word, type). Type would be noun, verb, etc. I need to check what type of word it is before I replace it. How would you do that?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I follow. What type of database? If the database is small I would load it into memory and store it as a dictionary. Looking up the type would simply be `types[word]`.

Answer (score 5):

Given that you are free to modify `$noun$` etc. to your liking, best practise to do this nowadays is probably to using the `format` function on a string:

```
"What {noun} is {verb}?".format(noun="XXX", verb="YYY")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.sub('\$noun\$', 'the heck', 'What $noun$ is $verb$?')
Out[2]: 'What the heck is $verb$?'
```

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionary to hold the regular expression pattern and value. use the re.sub to replace the tokens.

```
dict = {
   "(\$noun\$)" : "ABC",
   "(\$verb\$)": "DEF"
} 
new_str=str
for key,value in dict.items():
   new_str=(re.sub(key, value, new_str))
print(new_str)
```

output:

```
What ABC is DEF?
```