# Python - replace word with another

Tags: python, html, file, replace, html-table

I have html table with 12 cells. Each cell has a word to be replaced. All of the words are identical. Also I have a list with 12 elements. Each element is a word. I need to replace each word with the appropriate word from the list. First word to be replaced with the first element, second with the second element and so on. Can you give me an example how to do this, I'm new at python?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538160/replacing-specific-words-in-a-string-python and https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html.

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = ['fist','second','thrid']

for word in words:
    yourText = yourText.replace('theOldWord',word,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, use the `replace` method.

```
word = "your_word"
new_word = "new_word"
html_text.replace(word, new_word)
```

> Also I have a list with 12 elements. Each element is a word. I need to replace each word with the appropriate word from the list.

Create a dictionary mapping "old word" to "new word"

```
>>> list = ["oldword0", "oldword1"]
>>> mapping = {"oldword0": "newword0", "oldword1": "newword1"}
>>> map(lambda x: mapping[x], list)
['newword0', 'newword1']
```