# python replace specific elements in a string

Tags: python, replace

I have a string `'1472_1 2014-6-19'` and I want to replace whatever number is after the underscore(in this case number one) with the word 'Normal', what I did was to find the index of the element that I want replaced:

```
print line.replace(line[line.find('_') + 1:line.find(' ')],'Normal', 1)
```

But instead of getting `'1472_Normal 2014-6-19'`, I got `'Normal472_1 2014-6-19'`
It seems like my code replace the first 1 instead of the one after the underscore.

I have read this post: [Replacing specific words in a string (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538160/replacing-specific-words-in-a-string-python) but still wondering is there a way to specify which element to be replaced instead of using regex?

And to be clear the number after underscore could be any number from 0 to 237

Comment: are you okay with using regex or you want to keep it as string operations?

Comment: You have to use regex. Anywhere where a value is not static requires wildcard. Which entails regex

Comment: Actually I want to avoid regex so I'm wondering is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @Enkri_ - It's okay if you don't understand it. I still don't understand some of them that get quite complicated. However, so you have some background this tool should become your best friend.  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Regex is not required here.

Comment: Might the number (in this case `1`) be two digits, or is it always only one digit?

Comment: `b = (a.split('_')[0]+'_Normal '+a.split(' ')[1])` don't work with `temp` values !

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it could be any number between 0 and 237

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str.partition()`:

```
first, delimiter, second = line.partition('_')
a, s, b = second.partition(' ')
print first + delimiter + 'Normal' + s + b
```

Comment: Edited to handle multiple digits after underscore (with another `partition()`).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 still have one question tho, what was the problem with the method I used in the original post?

Comment: `line[line.find('_') + 1:line.find(' ')]` evaluated to just `'1'`, so it replaced the first `'1'` that it found with `'Normal'`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks so much

Comment: You could fix it by removing the `+ 1` and adding an underscore before `Normal`: `line.replace(line[line.find('_') :line.find(' ')], '_Normal', 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

without regex if there is always a space after the digit which based on `line.find(' ')` there is, split once to divide the string and rstrip any digits:

```
s = '1472_1 2014-6-19'

a,b = s.split(None,1)

print("{}Normal {}".format(a.rstrip("0123456789"),b))) 
1472_Normal 2014-6-19
```

stripping will work for any amount of digits after the underscore.

With regex:

```
 import  re

s = '1472_1 2014-6-19'

print(re.sub("(?<=_)\d+","Normal",s))
1472_Normal 2014-6-19
```

Why your own code fails is because you have a `1` at the start of your string so you replace that not the one after the underscore

Comment: OP is specifically asking for a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

## no regex

```
string = '1472_1 2014-6-19'
to_replace = string[string.find('_'):string.find(' ')]
string = string.replace(to_replace,'_Normal')
print string
```

Comment: How do you know there will always be a space after? You don't sir

Comment: Beceause the OP is expecting that?

Comment: Ha hopefully! Then yes it can be this easy

Comment: the string he provided is obviously 'whatever date'. How do you know if there will be space, or no space? You don't sir.

Comment: Thanks guys, the data come with a space after

Comment: This removes the underscore entirely.

Comment: @TigerhwakT3 try running the code in your head, or in your computa

Comment: Weird - the first time I ran it it removed the underscore, but this time it didn't. ...Oh I see, I didn't include the `_` before the `Normal` in the `replace()`. :)

Comment: your eyes did, maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use RegEx, you could use slicing to isolate the section of the string to replace in. So for instance:

```
def replace_normal(s)
    ui = s.index('_')  # index of first underscore
    si = s.index(' ')  # index of first space
    return s[:ui+1] + 'Normal' + s[si:]

s1 = '1472_1 2014-6-19'
s2 = '1571_44 2014-7-24'

print replace_normal(s1)  # 1472_Normal 2014-6-19
print replace_normal(s2)  # 1571_Normal 2014-7-24
```