# replace string with string based on the origin content

Tags: python, regex, replace, substitution

I need to replace **macro(param)** with **param**

```
mystring = "function(macro(param)) { a = call(1)};"
```

and my goal is

```
"function(param) { a = call(1)};"
```

the param is variable, it has to work also for

```
mystring = "function(macro(another_param)) { a = call(1)};"
"function(another_param) { a = call(1)};"
```

and in the text around could be anything and this text should be not affected.

Comment: `mystring.replace('macro(param)', 'param')`?

Comment: Or `mystring.replace('macro(', '').replace('))', ')')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing specific words in a string (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538160/replacing-specific-words-in-a-string-python)

Comment: sorry for bad describing of the problem, param could be anything and .replace('))', ') is not good enough for me, because it could destroy another )) in my string.

Comment: If `param` can be variable then use a variable: `mystring.replace('macro(' + param + ')', param)`.

Comment: @Meloun See the edit on this one, it'll be slightly more efficient without the lambda, I had forgotten about the direct reference earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `re.sub`:

```
import re

>>> mystring = "function(macro(param)) { a = call(1)};"
>>> re.sub('macro\((.*?)\)', r'\1', mystring)
function(param) { a = call(1)};

>>> mystring = "function(macro(another_param)) { a = call(1)};"
>>> re.sub('macro\((.*?)\)', r'\1', mystring)
function(another_param) { a = call(1)};
```

Re searches for `macro(param***)` and puts `param***` into a group when it is found, the sub then replaces that entire match with only `param***`