# how to change the python string for example replace one word instead of another?

Tags: python, python-3.7

here problem is, I have the python string like "I love daddy and I love mom".in this string what I want is, "I love mom and I love daddy".

here is the python string

```
s='i love dad and  i love mom',
s1=s.replace('dad','mom'),
print(s1)
```

Here is the output  is : i love mom and i love mom

But i need the output is : i love mom and i love dad

Comment: Could you provide more examples? You want to exchange words?

Comment: just see the description and write your comment

Comment: Please allow us to Google that for you: [python replace word in string site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+replace+word+in+string+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing specific words in a string (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538160/replacing-specific-words-in-a-string-python)

Answer (score 1):

Create a dict with the replacements

```
replacements = {
    'daddy': 'mom',
    'mom': 'daddy',
}
```

Create a function to return the correct replacement from the dict based on a match object:

```
def find_replacement(m):
    return replacements[m.group(1)]
```

Then use re.sub

```
text = "I love daddy and I love mom"
regex = r'({})'.format(r'|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in replacements))
result = re.sub(regex, find_replacement, text)
print(result)
```

Comment: String format doesn't do word replacement - it only replaces the formatting placeholders, like `{foo}`...